WSO2 IS 5.10 : Unable to use claims of the resident user store in the token generated by a service provider using OIDC Federation for authentication
I'm workfing on a legacy project that uses WSO2 IS 5.10 (migration is not on the table right now)
I'm trying to implementing a scenario where:
I use an OIDC-able external IDP as source of authentication but want to retrieve claims from the profile of a local user that share the same UserPrincipalName

To achieve that, here's what I've done :

I create a user with upn USER1 in the user store of wso2 under domain A. I provide in its default profile an email and some roles
I create an identity provider (WSO2IDP) under domain A that connects to the service provider (EXTSP) of a OIDC-able federated identity provider (EXTIDP)

That step implies inputting all the OIDC configuration provided in EXTSP and EXTIDP. All configuration was retrieved from the EXTIDP and its well-kwown url.
WSOIDP Configuration
Only parameters i'm not sure about are Alias (I suspect it does not have any impact) and OpenID Connect User ID Location (not sure what it does)
I was forced to urlEncode the space in Additional Query Parameters as wso2 was throwing a malformed url error.


I create a service provider in WSO2 under domain A (WSO2SP) that use a federated authentication step using WSO2IDP. I ask for 3 local mandatory claims Claim Configuration:

http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress
http://wso2.org/claims/role
http://wso2.org/claims/userprincipal


I create a user in EXTIDP with username USER1


What I expect:
When initiating a login to WSO2SP, I am redirected to EXTSP login screen.
I input username and password of user created in step 4
I am redirected to my oauthCallbackUrl (configured in WSO2SP Inbound Authentication Configuration) with a code. I can exchange this code to my WSO2SP for:

id token
access token
refresh token

At this point I expect my id token to contain mandatory claims of step 3 populated with values of user USER1 profile created at step 1 but I always get an error page telling me that some mandatory read only claims could not be found.
I suspect that wso2 have a hard time linking the authenticated user from EXTIDP to my local user but I do not know where to go from here.

Extra informations:

I tried multiples variations of claim mappings in the WSO2IDP to map the sub claim to local claim http://wso2.org/claims/userprincipal but nothing seems to work.

I retrieved a token directly from EXTSDP using authorization_code grant to be sure that the required info (sub claim) was in the id token retrieved and in the userinfo endpoint. It was present in both instances.


I do not know which information is needed to solve this problem but if you ask for precisions in comments I will be happy to oblige.

You could use the account linking feature of WSO2 IS to link the federated identity from EXTSDP with an existing local identity in WSO2 IS. This could be done using an adaptive script. When the user authenticates with the federated IdP, the adaptive authentication script can retrieve the 'sub' value from the federated user object and search for any local user who has the same value for the 'UserPrincipalName' claim. Then you can use the doAssociationWithLocalUser(fedUser, localUsername, tenantDomain, userStoreDomain) (https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/references/adaptive-authentication-js-api-reference/#doassociationwithlocaluserfeduser-localusername-tenantdomain-userstoredomain) adaptive authentication function to link the federated account with the matching local account.
The 'scenario 1' explained in the medium article - https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/social-account-linking-with-wso2-identity-server-78b8a566e225 explains the specific flow that you have to follow.
